# How to obtain formatted value on a field instead of actual value?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a table with an **EmployeeID** as type *Autonumber* and it has the following format "\C000000".  So instead of first employee record having an id of *1* it has an id of C000001.  The reason it is set as Autonumber is so that it increases every time I create a new record in the database.

The problem is that i'm trying to reference that value to create hyperlinks to open that employee's folder on my server.  All folders in the computer are named like the formatted id (example: *C000001*).  When I write `"#C:\Users\Default\Desktop\" & [EmployeeID] & "#"` the hyperlink that returns is *C:\Users\Default\Desktop\1*

It is taking the original value (1) instead of the formatted value (*C000001*). Naming the folders (*1,2,3,4*) instead of *C00*... is not an option.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were creating the string with VBA, you could use a `Format()` expression to apply the same format to the stored *EmployeeID* value:

```vb
"#C:\Users\Default\Desktop\" & Format([EmployeeID], "\C000000") & "#"
```

However, if this is for a data macro, you can't use `Format()`.  In that case you can concatenate 6 zeros plus *EmployeeID* and take the right-most 6 characters:

```vb
"#C:\Users\Default\Desktop\C" & Right("000000" & [EmployeeID], 6) & "#"
```